# Giving users options to change the launcher icon

Tags: android, android-manifest

While I know that there is no native way of changing the `ic_launcher` in the `manifest`, I'm wondering if anyone has came across a smart workaround for allowing users to choose the launcher icon that displays within the app launcher.

My current thoughts is that there may be a way to do this using the `mipmap` resource folder to do something similar.

**App Examples**

- Deliveroo
- Monzo

Comment: If it is a fixed set of options, in theory you could use `<activity-alias>`. Have one alias for each option and enable only that component using `PackageManager`.

Comment: @CommonsWare that's a really good idea! I'll look into that and let you know how it goes. Thank you!